# How can I remove the host name and domain from window titles

Tags: x11, xfce, opensuse

I installed OpenSUSE Leap 15.4 with the XFCE desktop environment. The hostname and the domain are appended to every window title by default:

[image: Example window with host name and domain in title bar]

I don't like this behavior. It distracts me especially because it doesn't contain any useful information. How can I remove the hostname and the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently occurs in OpenSUSE when the hostname isn't set.  According to https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/hhsgtl/in_localhostlocaldomain_message_at_the_end_of/, setting your hostname using the command:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <hostname>
```

will remedy this problem, with the additional effect of changing the desktop name.

Of course, you'll want to substitute the name of your choice for `<hostname>`.

Note that it may be necessary to use `hostname` in place of `set-hostname` in the `hostnamectl` command.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the trick.